# OpenMDAO - information on cycles

Tags: time, openmdao

In OpenMDAO, is there any way to get the analytics about the execution of the nonlinear solvers within a coupled model (containing multiple cycles and subcycles), such as the number of iterations within each of the cycles, and execution time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though there is no specific functionality to get this exact data, you should be able to get the information you need from case record data which includes iteration counts and time-stamps. So you'd have to do a bit of analysis on the first/last case of a specific run of a solver to compute the run times. Iteration counts should be very strait forward.

This question seems closely related to [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71296031/openmdao-hierarchical-solvers-recording/71302315?noredirect=1#comment126041543_71302315), recently posted which did identify a bug in OpenMDAO. ([Issue #2453](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/issues/2453)). Until that bug is fixed, you'll need to use the case names to separate out which cases belong to which cycles, since you can only currently add the recorders to the components/groups and not to the nested solvers themselves. But the naming of the cases should still allow you to pull the data you need out.